# Extjs Image change dynamically through browse

Tags: image, dynamic, upload, extjs4, src

I have written application [like this](http://www.uploadscreenshot.com/image/809867/4680186). But when i click on EDIT it is giving pop-up of some editable fields. In that PROFILE-PHOTO also there. All text fields updating but IMAGE is not updating.Code is [here](http://pastebin.com/YGdJtPYr)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Ext.getCmp('dformfile').getEl().dom.src = 'newurl.gif';`